# Monitoring Search Components Status?

Tags: search, alert, sharepoint-on-prem, monitoring

Our Intranet heavily relies on the search service from displaying documents to showing various news articles.

We now had 2 situations where the Index Partition was degraded and since this happened over night I did not notice. We have a monitoring system in place that besides hard-disk space or RAM/CPU utilization checks for the various SharePoint services. Since the Search service is still running even with a degraded Index Partition this is rather "useless" and brings me to my question:

**Is there any way to monitor the status of the individual search components so we get a notification (email, list entry in SP etc...) when something is wrong?**

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the SharePoint Search Health Reports: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2016/02/01/announcing-the-search-health-reports-srx-for-sharepoint-search-diagnostics/ they are very detailed and you can pick and choose which test you want to run.

I wrote up a blog post a while back on how to take the results of the reports and build a PowerBI dashboard. You could easily do a Send Mail instead, but I like the PowerBI solution because it's is easily viewed on mobile devices.

https://searchexplained.com/create-a-search-service-status-dashboard/

Comment: Thank you! Even though I was kinda hoping for an easier solution (Enable Feature X > Finished!!) this does help me in monitoring the search ;-)

Comment: Nope, sorry, there is no such feature...even though we have asked for it. External monitoring is your best bet.